# How to deploy system dependent services with docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm-mode

I must deploy a service `service1` (with `username/image`) into three different systems (**node1**, **node2** & **node3**). Due to the architectural differences in the systems, I built the `username/image` for the all devices and tagged it as `username/image:node1`, `username/image:node2` and `username/image:node3` (for **node1**, **node2** and **node3** respectively). However, I created the following `compose.yml` file to deploy the service into the cluster:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    image: username/image:node${nodeID}
    deploy:
      replicas: 6
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
        constraints:
          - node.labels.with_imgTag==node${imgTag}
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

First, I set labels to the nodes as:

```
docker node update --label-add with_imgTag=node1 node1
docker node update --label-add with_imgTag=node2 node2
docker node update --label-add with_imgTag=node3 node3
```

and then deploy service1 with the following command:

```
for ((c=1; c<=3; c++)) do nodeID=$c imgTag=$c docker stack deploy -c compose.yml stack-4-service-1; done
```

In the `stack-4-service-1`, the `docker stack deploy` updates (the previous service or at least the running one) with a new one into any node (as the `restart_policy` is specified). I want to deploy the `service1` where a node is not hosting `service1` at the moment (by specifying `max_replicas_per_node`). How can I do that? - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A service has a 1:1 relationship with its image so if you want to use "replicas" and "max_replicas_per_node" to manage how a service is scheduled on nodes you need to have a single image.

If by architectural differences you mean cpu or OS architecture then build a multiplatform image so you can use a single image ref. If you mean different configurations, then use mounts or volumes unique to each node to carry the per-node differences.

In the case that volumes and mounts can't be used, you could build one image with all N variants and use environment variables that use service template parameters to control behaviour in your startup script.

e.g.

```yaml
services:
  service1:
    image: user/image:latest
    environment:
      THIS_NODE: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - |
      case $$THIS_NODE in
        node1)
          app /data/node1
          ;;
        node2)
          app /data/node2
          ;;
      esac
```

Comment: Here, `architectural differences` means (in my case) #GPU architecture. For example, `Nvidia Clara AGX` has compute capacity of `7.5`. On the other hand, `Nvidia Jetson Xavier NX Dev kit` has compute capacity of `7.2`. In my use case, `service1` is dependent on the GPU architecture. In the swarm cluster, the request for `service1` should be routed to either `Clara` or `Xavier`. How can I do that?

Comment: Every guide ive seen re GPU and swarm makes use of swarms "generic_resource" capability.. It's used in kind of the opposite way to your query: you tag each unique resource in the nodes daemon.json and then deploy services with a resource request that matches a tag. Don't know if it will work for you.

Comment: could you please update your answer or share some resources you mentioned above? Thanks!